# Update custom price woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, cart

I am developing a plugin which works with WooCommerce and need update custom price just after submit order in checkout page.

**Question:** Is it possible?

I have tried with:

```
header('Location: http://myweb.com/?add-to-cart=477');

// define the woocommerce_review_order_after_submit callback 
function action_woocommerce_review_order_after_submit(  ) { 

    $custom_price = 10; // This will be your custome price  
    $target_product_id = 477;
    foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $value ) {
        if ( $value['product_id'] == $target_product_id ) {
            $value['data']->price = $custom_price;
        }
    }
}
     
// add the action 
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_submit',     
'action_woocommerce_review_order_after_submit');
```

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Woocommerce add to cart with custom price](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32361369/woocommerce-add-to-cart-with-custom-price)

Comment: Did it worked? select my answer if it worked

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it in another hook, that one will be overridden after calculating totals, you have to do in `woocommerce_before_calculate_totals` hook, so change the `add_action` call to:

`add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'action_woocommerce_review_order_after_submit' );`